# Change woocommerce image URL to match the Product title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I'm looking for a way to change the images uploaded from original file-name to the product title for example :

```
www.URL.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/DSC0031-22-800x563.webp
to 
www.URL.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/PRODUCT-TITLE.webp
```

is there any option to do that automatically instead of rename file name and upload it ??

Thank you :))

Comment: How do you see this then? during the creation of a product you can add (upload) an image but also thumbnails, what name do those images get? and what about other posts of a different type than product where you can add images? like some more information

Comment: when i visit the product and click on copy image url you get the url of it and its on the first format with the name of the file i uploaded , all the images get the file name from my desktop for example if i uploaded a file named "final.jpg" from my computer the url will be www.URL.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/final.jpg